# Knockout.js keyboard selection of select bound to observable crashes IE

Tags: knockout.js

Strange problem. I have a select box bound to a large array that updates an observable. There is nothing fancy about this other than the array size. Here is a *jsfiddle* with a complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/mikebruner/s2SFj/11/

And here is the code with an abbreviated version of the array:

**Markup**:

```
Value: <span data-bind="text: technicalOwner"></span>
<p>
Field: 
<select name="technicalOwner" id="technicalOwner" 
    data-bind="options: technicalOwnerOptions
                                , optionsCaption: 'Select...'
                                , optionsText: 'Value'
                                , optionsValue: 'Name'
                                , value: technicalOwner">
</select>
```

**Model**:

```
function CommercialEntryViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.technicalOwner = ko.observable("");
    self.technicalOwnerOptions = [{"Name":"aapr","Value":"aapr"},{"Name":"abf","Value":"abf"}  .... ];  
};
```

Using **IE10**, when I select a value from the select box using the mouse, the observable gets updated and all is well. BUT if use the keyboard to select a value in the `select-box` and then tab off the field, IE10 crashes.

Some other observations:

This works fine in Chrome. Appears to be an IE10 problem. I don't have other versions of IE at my disposal to test, though it seems to crash in Compatibility Mode as well.

If I take out the observable, everything works fine.

If I reduce the number of items in the array, everything works fine.

I admit the javascript array could certainly be tightened up (this is normally coming from objects getting serialized into JSON). But I think it is okay syntactically and still ought to work.

Comment: Your fiddle runs find in IE10 for me.

Comment: Hmmmm OK thanks for that info. I've got numerous people at my company all experiencing the same behavior, pretty frustrating.

Comment: Here is a version with 1000 array entries (http://jsfiddle.net/s2SFj/14/) that runs fine for me, but it's a little sluggish (not so in Chrome). -- For large inputs it's advisable to use some sort of autocomplete anyway instead of huge select boxes. Not exactly a solution, but hey... realisticly nobody wants to use a 1000-entry dropdown list.

Comment: You might also give `<datalist>` a try, [according to MSDN IE10 supports it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772925(v=vs.85).aspx). I happen to have created [a `datalist` binding for knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19867498/18771) just yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same thing happening, and upgrading to Knockout version 3.0.0 fixed the problem.